# How to animate hair without major lag? Hair Dynamics 3.0.1

Tags: animation, transforms, baking, hair

I have a model that I have animated with clothing in a walking simulation.

My process was to rig my model using Mixamo, import that model into marvelous designer to animate the clothing, and then bring it back to blender to animate the hair.
However the hair is extremely laggy when trying to *bake*, what are some ways I can remedy this and get a clean animation?

Any and all help appreciated, I am still learning when it comes to the workflow/process of things.

Would shorter, less hair do the trick?
[image]
Believe it or not the animation of the hair when I previously baked it looked a lot better than now.

[image]
(1 side of the hair baked, I have 2 particle systems on the head for left and right scalp.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Basically looking for someone to tell me how I am approaching this wrong so I can correct my ways. Why does the hair specifically spazz out when the animation gets going?

Answer (score 0):

Having more child particles and less "real particles" can help with performance, if you weren't already using the child particle system. You could also try re-keying in comb edit mode to a lower number. Also try "Remove doubles" in comb mode, there might be double particles.